# Creating a pie chart inside a donut chart in apexcharts

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, pie-chart, apexcharts

I am trying to add a chart in apexcharts which is a pie chart inside a donut, looks like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/p8e3taq1/) example, which uses `chart.js`:

```
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: [
        "#2ecc71",
        "#3498db",
      ],
      data: [433, 44]
    }]
  }
});
</script>
```

and I couldn't find a way to do that.

I would have used the example in the link I've added, but it looks laggy (hovering isn't good) and it isn't very responsive.